# node-postgres: how to prepare a statement without executing the query?

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

I want to create a "prepared statement" in postgres using the node-postgres module. I want to create it without binding it to parameters because the binding will take place in a loop.

In the [documentation](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#method-query-prepared) i read :

```
query(object config, optional function callback) : Query
If _text_ and _name_ are provided within the config, the query will result in the creation of a prepared statement.
```

I tried

```
client.query({"name":"mystatement", "text":"select id from mytable where id=$1"});
```

but when I try passing only the text & name keys in the config object, I get an exception :

(translated) message is binding 0 parameters but the prepared statement expects 1

Is there something I am missing ? How do you create/prepare a statement without binding it to specific value in order to avoid re-preparing the statement in every step of a loop ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just found an [answer on this issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/24) by the author of node-postgres.

> With node-postgres the first time you issue a named query it is
>   parsed, bound, and executed all at once. Every subsequent query issued
>   on the same connection with the same name will automatically skip the
>   "parse" step and only rebind and execute the already planned query.
>
> Currently node-postgres does not support a way to create a named,
>   prepared query and not execute the query. This feature is supported
>   within libpq and the client/server protocol (used by the pure
>   javascript bindings), but I've not directly exposed it in the API. I
>   thought it would add complexity to the API without any real benefit.
>   Since named statements are bound to the client in which they are
>   created, if the client is disconnected and reconnected or a different
>   client is returned from the client pool, the named statement will no
>   longer work (it requires a re-parsing).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pg-prepared](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-prepared) for that:

```
var prep = require('pg-prepared')

// First prepare statement without binding parameters
var item = prep('select id from mytable where id=${id}')

// Then execute the query and bind parameters in loop
for (i in [1,2,3]) {
  client.query(item({id: i}), function(err, result) {...})
}
```

Comment: `pg-prepared` does something different than what is OP is asking for. it gives the ability to use named placeholders in queries.

Comment: OP wants to create prepared statements without binding parameter values on creation. This is what happens on the example with pg-prepared. First you create the statement without binding the parameter values and store it in var item. Then you call it with the parameters. So OP can use this by creating the statement without variables binding and then call it with the parameter values in the loop.

Comment: in your case, the *database* has to prepare the query again and again. what OP wants is to relieve the db by preparing the stmt only once. Accorrding to the accepted answer, pg-prepared could reach this if it was giving a unique "name" attribute to the query - cf https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Prepared-Statements

Answer (score 1):

Update: Reading your question again, here's what I believe you need to do. You need to pass a "value" array as well.

Just to clarify; where you would normally "prepare" your query, just prepare the object you pass to it, without the value array. Then where you would normally "execute" your query, set the value array in the object and pass it to the query. If it's the first time, the driver will do the actual prepare for you the first time around, and simple do binding and execution for the rest of the iteration.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that the prepared statement will be executed with the 'whatever' values used at creation time. It also feels akward to use the first iteration of the loop for creation

Comment: That's how the API is designed I guess, at least that's what I've gotten from reading the docs and using it in one of my own projects. The API expects you to create your query object when you need to use it, and then it will figure out whether it needs to prepare a statement or not depending on whether it knows about whatever you put in `text` already.